# my GUI doesn't run as executable using pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I've used pyinstaller to convert my Tkinter GUI to an executable file. When I run the exe through command prompt, it reads it but does nothing (I know it reads it because when it has errors they are shown). I'm very new to programming so I wrote a simpler script to generate a window only, converted this to exe and encountered the same problem. Any fundamental rules I'm not aware of that will correct this? Here's the simple code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

def startup():
    global CODES
    CODES = Tk()
    CODES.title("TEST WINDOW - PYTHON EXECUTABLE")
    CODES.geometry("1555x569+20+20")
    return CODES.mainloop
startup()
```

Saved it as "test.py", converted to exe by "pyinstaller test.py -F" in Command Prompt. When run, it just pauses then returns to Command Prompt

Comment: The same happens when you put this code in a .py file and run it, has nothing to do with pyinstaller. The problem is that you never call the mainloop, you just return a reference to the function. Change `return CODES.mainloop` to `return CODES.mainloop()`.

Comment: As @fhdrsdg has shown you problem it not with pyinstaller rather with the code! change your code recompile and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is fixable by using this command in your terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole test.py
```

This will save your Python script as an executable file.
Hope this helps!